# Problems configuring System.Net in Mono

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono, web-config

I have tried to configure the System.net node in Web.config on my Mono project.

I keep getting this exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Error deserializing configuration section defaultProxy: Unrecognized attribute 'enabled'. (/usr/share/nginx/aspnet/Web.config line 1)

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Configuration.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo config, Boolean createDefaultInstance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebRequest.GetDefaultWebProxy () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebRequest.get_DefaultWebProxy () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.get_Select () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebRequest:.ctor (System.Uri)
  at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.SetupRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I can not figure out how to get my application to either accept the defaultProxy node with the enabled attribute set to true or to use some other settings.

If I remove the System.net node from Web.config, the part of the application that uses the WebClient times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have found a bug in mono. The [`DefaultProxySection` constructor seems to forget to add the attribute properties to the collection](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Configuration/DefaultProxySection.cs#L61-L65), so the config reader doesn't know about them.

Note that the default for the `enabled` property is `true` so you can omit that setting as a workaround for your problem.

Nevertheless, please report the bug in [bugzilla.xamarin.com](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com)

Comment: Was a bug reported for this?

Comment: No bug was filed, but it should now be fixed with https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/4954 :)

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing.
To get around this bug, you can either set

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
```

to NULL or to

```
new System.Net.WebProxy();
```

before you do a WebRequest.

Example:

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy();


System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
```